# Install Oracle on my vista desktop

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to learn oracle and that is why I want to install Oracle on my vista machine. Could you please let me know where can I download the installer from?

Could you guys let me know about any books that I can start working with Oracle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would install and run [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html) ("Oracle XE"). It'll be easier to install and sufficient for your needs.

For the rest see [What is a good Oracle reference book for a beginner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989984/what-is-a-good-oracle-reference-book-for-a-beginner)

Comment: +1 for XE. I wonder if they'll ever upgrade it to 11g, though.

Comment: @Thilo: probably when 12g (or whatever letter is all the rage by then) comes out.

Comment: Fixed broken link. Now it's 11g :D

Answer (score 0):

Try [Oracle SQL and PL/SQL](http://sqlandplsql.com/) for basics